# How do I add a third node to a 2-node Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using Cassandra v3.9. I updated the config files as shown below but 25.80.44.50 won't join the cluster (it was formally part of the 2-node clusrter along with 25.80.44.51).

When I reverted back to a 2 node cluster, the database was corrupted and I had to restore from a backup.

## Node 1

### Config:

```
[root@program-node01-vm conf]# egrep -v "^$|^#|^ *#" /var/lib/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
  - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "25.80.44.51,25.80.44.52"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 25.80.44.50
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: 25.80.44.50
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    require_client_auth: false
    require_endpoint_verification: false
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    require_client_auth: false
internode_compression: none
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
```

### LSOF:

```
[root@program-node01 conf]# lsof -P -n -p 13328 | grep -i tcp
java    13328 cassandra   93u     IPv4            7854361       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:46464 (LISTEN)
java    13328 cassandra   94u     IPv4            7854362       0t0        TCP *:7199 (LISTEN)
java    13328 cassandra   97u     IPv4            7803257       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:7000->25.80.44.51:53828 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra   99u     IPv4            7866406       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:37347->25.80.44.51:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  101u     IPv4            7828918       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:51688->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  104u     IPv4            7866413       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:7000->25.80.44.51:41813 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  105u     IPv4            7752003       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:7000->25.80.44.52:50307 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  113u     IPv4            7869505       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:34373->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  194u     IPv4            7826676       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:60348->25.80.44.51:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  220u     IPv4            7803243       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:7000 (LISTEN)
java    13328 cassandra  336u     IPv4            7803259       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:9042 (LISTEN)
java    13328 cassandra  337u     IPv4            7752004       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:7000->25.80.44.50:37007 (ESTABLISHED)
java    13328 cassandra  340u     IPv4            7884819       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.50:37007->25.80.44.50:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

This proves that this node (25.80.44.50) is connected (via tcp) to both the other nodes (25.80.44.51 and 25.80.44.52). However, I do not see connections for port 9042 similar to 7000. I thought 9042 was the node-node communications port.

### Netstat

```
[root@program-node01 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 7000
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:7000        25.80.44.51:53828       ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:7000        25.80.44.50:37007       ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:51688       25.80.44.52:7000        ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:7000        25.80.44.52:50307       ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:37007       25.80.44.50:7000        ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:7000        25.80.44.51:41813       ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:34373       25.80.44.52:7000        ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:37347       25.80.44.51:7000        ESTABLISHED 13328/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:60348       25.80.44.51:7000        ESTABLISHED 13328/java
[root@program-node01 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 9042
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.50:9042        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13328/java
[root@program-node01 conf]#
```

### Nodetool info:

```
[root@program-node01 conf]# /var/lib/cassandra/bin/nodetool info
ID                     : 5db50d6d-3eae-4a47-b7c9-4743cd80ec99
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 50.69 MiB
Generation No          : 1616531552
Uptime (seconds)       : 5663
Heap Memory (MB)       : 80.06 / 7987.25
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 0.07
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 132, size 24.41 KiB, capacity 100 MiB, 94 hits, 161 requests, 0.584 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 10, size 1.17 KiB, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 14, size 896 KiB, capacity 480 MiB, 70 misses, 267 requests, 0.738 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 91.24266615492786%
Token                  : (node is not joined to the cluster)
[root@program-node01 conf]#
```

**Here is what I believe is the problem!**
**The `(node is not joined to the cluster)` for `Token:`**

## Node 2

### Config:

```
[root@program-node02-vm conf]# egrep -v "^$|^#|^ *#" /var/lib/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
  - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "25.80.44.50,25.80.44.52"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 25.80.44.51
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: 25.80.44.51
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    require_client_auth: false
    require_endpoint_verification: false
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    require_client_auth: false
internode_compression: none
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
```

### LSOF:

```
[root@program-node02 conf]# lsof -P -n -p 12100 | grep -i tcp
java    12100 cassandra   72u     IPv4            7457886       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000->25.80.44.52:39067 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   73u     IPv4            7441813       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:55223->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   76u     IPv4            7452718       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:41813->25.80.44.50:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   89u     IPv4            7475374       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:39020 (LISTEN)
java    12100 cassandra   90u     IPv4            7475375       0t0        TCP *:7199 (LISTEN)
java    12100 cassandra   92u     IPv4            7429183       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:44473->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   93u     IPv4            6972054       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:33449->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   94u     IPv4            7451798       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000->25.80.44.50:60348 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra   97u     IPv4            7441814       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000->25.80.44.51:33562 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra  235u     IPv4            7464346       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000 (LISTEN)
java    12100 cassandra  236u     IPv4            7291404       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000->25.80.44.50:37347 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra  237u     IPv4            7451793       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:7000->25.80.44.52:59547 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra  325u     IPv4            7429185       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:9042 (LISTEN)
java    12100 cassandra  326u     IPv4            6972044       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:53828->25.80.44.50:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    12100 cassandra  329u     IPv4            7291409       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.51:33562->25.80.44.51:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

### Netstat:

```
[root@program-node02 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 7000
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:33562       25.80.44.51:7000        ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        25.80.44.50:37347       ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        25.80.44.51:33562       ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        25.80.44.52:59547       ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        25.80.44.52:39067       ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:41813       25.80.44.50:7000        ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:53828       25.80.44.50:7000        ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:7000        25.80.44.50:60348       ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:44473       25.80.44.52:7000        ESTABLISHED 12100/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:55223       25.80.44.52:7000        ESTABLISHED 12100/java
[root@program-node02 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 9042
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.51:9042        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12100/java
[root@program-node02 conf]#
```

### Nodetool info:

```
[root@program-node02 conf]# /var/lib/cassandra/bin/nodetool info
ID                     : fa92ebd8-32f8-4f4f-bc85-37afd86a20c2
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 50.71 MiB
Generation No          : 1616531553
Uptime (seconds)       : 5673
Heap Memory (MB)       : 1122.51 / 7987.25
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 0.07
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 110, size 22.55 KiB, capacity 100 MiB, 108 hits, 173 requests, 0.624 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 4, size 480 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 493, size 30.81 MiB, capacity 480 MiB, 567 misses, 796 requests, 0.288 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 100.0%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
[root@program-node02 conf]#
```

## Node 3

### Config:

```
[root@program-node03 conf]# egrep -v "^$|^#|^ *#" /var/lib/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
  - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "25.80.44.50,25.80.44.51"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 25.80.44.52
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: 25.80.44.52
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    require_client_auth: false
    require_endpoint_verification: false
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    require_client_auth: false
internode_compression: none
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
```

### LSOF:

```
[root@program-node03 conf]#  lsof -P -n -p 30557 | grep -i tcp
java    30557 cassandra   79u     IPv4           32883385       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.52:35735 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   80u     IPv4           32848102       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:50307->25.80.44.50:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   84u     IPv4           32833187       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.51:44473 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   87u     IPv4           32848098       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.50:51688 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   89u     IPv4           32848099       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:39067->25.80.44.51:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   95u     IPv4           32844289       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:33308 (LISTEN)
java    30557 cassandra   96u     IPv4           32844290       0t0        TCP *:7199 (LISTEN)
java    30557 cassandra   97u     IPv4           32848100       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.50:34373 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra   98u     IPv4           32887275       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:35735->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra  100u     IPv4           32848101       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.52:37285 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra  212u     IPv4           32833190       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:9042 (LISTEN)
java    30557 cassandra  215u     IPv4           32853056       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:37285->25.80.44.52:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra  216u     IPv4           32851005       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.51:33449 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra  226u     IPv4           32833179       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000 (LISTEN)
java    30557 cassandra  228u     IPv4           32833185       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:59547->25.80.44.51:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
java    30557 cassandra  229u     IPv4           32833186       0t0        TCP 25.80.44.52:7000->25.80.44.51:55223 (ESTABLISHED)
```

### Netstat:

```
[root@program-node03 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 7000
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        25.80.44.51:44473       ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:37285       25.80.44.52:7000        ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        25.80.44.50:34373       ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        25.80.44.50:51688       ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:50307       25.80.44.50:7000        ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:59547       25.80.44.51:7000        ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        25.80.44.52:37285       ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:39067       25.80.44.51:7000        ESTABLISHED 30557/java
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:7000        25.80.44.51:55223       ESTABLISHED 30557/java
[root@program-node03 conf]# netstat -anp | grep 9042
tcp        0      0 25.80.44.52:9042        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30557/java
[root@program-node03 conf]#
```

### Nodetool info:

```
[root@program-node03 conf]# /var/lib/cassandra/bin/nodetool info
ID                     : 5db50d6d-3eae-4a47-b7c9-4743cd80ec99
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 47.3 MiB
Generation No          : 1616531553
Uptime (seconds)       : 5674
Heap Memory (MB)       : 81.91 / 1916.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 0.07
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 93, size 12.27 KiB, capacity 95 MiB, 164 hits, 221 requests, 0.742 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 8, size 960 bytes, capacity 47 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 420, size 26.25 MiB, capacity 447 MiB, 559 misses, 866 requests, 0.355 recent hit rate, NaN microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 100.0%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
[root@program-node03 conf]#
```

Comment: Note: I point out where I see an issue at the bottom of the "Nodetool info" paragraph for Node 1.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to build a cluster using the `AllowAll` auth classes to begin with.  It's _definitely_ not a good idea to do that while also listing your IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
The issue was in the database data. Using the above configurations, I:

1. Stopped all 3 nodes of Cassandra.
2. Deleted the database from nodes 2 and 3
3. Restored the node 1 DB from a backup I made before changing anything
4. Started Cassandra on node 1 (and let it "settle")
5. Started Cassandra on node 2 (and let it replicate all data to it)
6. Started Cassandra on node 3 (and let it replicate all data to it)

My only remaining issue is that only 68% (ish) of the data is owned by each node. Since I am looking for fault tolerance, I believe I need to change the replication_factor to 3 for all data in my schema.

```
[root@program-node01 ~]# /var/lib/cassandra/bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  25.80.44.52  45.77 MiB  256          67.2%             bcee7571-a2eb-402e-b86f-c7e3327a8b7d  rack1
UN  25.80.44.50  51.93 MiB  256          68.0%             cc96b4c7-d55e-4b32-80aa-a114bf8af7d1  rack1
UN  25.80.44.51  51.89 MiB  256          64.8%             fa92ebd8-32f8-4f4f-bc85-37afd86a20c2  rack1
```

Comment: Nice job, Bill.  Glad you got it fixed!

Comment: I did update the seeds to reflect node1 & node2 for all configurations.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `seeds` list to be the same across all 3 nodes.

Right now, it's different for each node...which works only when one of the nodes in the seed list is already running.  The first node in the cluster needs to find itself in that seed list.

In a small cluster like this, I'd take the `seeds` setting from your first node, and make sure all other nodes' `seeds` properties match it:

```
- seeds: "25.80.44.51,25.80.44.52"
```

That would be a good start.